# Computing datetime from a string?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a date and time in a csv file like this : `20140618123022` and the column format is `datetime`, the question is what is the best way to convert this string to '2014-06-18 12:30:22' datetime format ?

I will create a pool procedure to do this ..

and i was thinking to make use or `RIGHT()` and `LEFT()` and `concatenation` , is this the right way  ?

```
     CONVERT([datetime],(((((((((CONVERT([varchar](4),[data],(0))+'-')+substring([data],(5),
    (2)))+'-')+substring([data],(7),(2)))+' ')+substring([data],(9),
    (2)))+':')+substring([data],(11),(2)))+':')+substring([data],(13),(2)),(0))
```

Comment: The best way depends on the database.  What database are you using?

Comment: Here is an article to start with: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/88152/ Your best choice is probably a CLR to achieve your goal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @a varchar(20)
set @a='20140618123022'

select convert(datetime,(left(@a,4)+'-'+substring(@a,5,2)+'-'+substring(@a,7,2)+' '+substring(@a,9,2)+':'+substring(@a,11,2)+':'+right(@a,2)))
```

OR this!

```
select convert(datetime,(left(@a,8)+' '+substring(@a,9,2)+':'+substring(@a,11,2)+':'+right(@a,2)))
```

[DEmo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/35753)

--returns

```
2014-06-18 12:30:22.000
```

Comment: The separation of year, month and day is not needed, '20140618 12:30:22' is parsed correctly

Answer (score 1):

You can use STUFF function as show below:

```
DECLARE @D CHAR(14) = '20140619123022'
SELECT STUFF(
        STUFF(
            STUFF(
                STUFF(
                  STUFF(@D,5,0,'-')
                    ,8,0,'-')
                ,11,0,' ')
            ,14,0,':')
        ,17,0,':')
```

You will have to make sure that your string length is consistent, i.e it's a 14 character length string.
Fiddle link: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/35769/0